# Scroll Bottom Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть блок div в который динамически добавляются другие блоки div.
Как делать автоматически скролл к последнему добавленному?

Структура немного другая html:

```
<div class="list">
<div class="dialog145_151"><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div></div>

<div class="dialog145_153"><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div></div>
</div>
```

В данном примере блок **list** и блоки **dialog145_151**, **dialog145_153** имеют фиксированную высоту, в которые добавляются блоки div, к последнему их которых нужно сделать прокрутку.

Answer (score 1):

$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('.list').children().last().offset().top
}, 450);

Вызывать этот код нужно каждый раз, когда вставляется новый элемент.

Comment: зачем 'html, body', может там .list?

Comment: У меня работает!